# Open HKCR and HKCU for another user from unprivileged app (via RPC)

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, rpc

Having trouble implementing cross-user registry access in an unprivileged app (via local RPC). Here's the situation:

- I'm writing a sandboxed app that can access an RPC server, but has almost no access to the registry.
- I have an RPC server running as LocalSystem on the same machine as the sandboxed app. The RPC transport used is LRPC (ncalrpc).
- I want to enable the app to browse various parts of the registry - including keys owned by other users - *without* editing the ACLs on the registry keys to give this app access directly.

Currently, the app calls into the RPC server, which opens an HKEY to the requested path and then uses [`DuplicateHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx) to pass it back to the app.

- This works fine for HKLM and HKU. The app receives the HKEY and can use it to enumerate subkeys and read values.
- For subkeys of those hives, it also works well. The app gets the subkey and can enumerate its contents.
- I want something that will handle HKCU (which is entirely per-user) and HKCR (which is a union of the system `classes` root and the per-user `classes` root) for users other than LocalSystem (what the RPC service runs as).

What I've tried so far:

- Having the app try opening the root keys itself, then pass them (via `DuplicateHandle`) to the RPC server instead of the predefined keys.

  - This doesn't work even for the app's own user; the app can open the keys (with very limited access) but the server apparently can't open sub-keys of these passed-in root HKEYs (possibly due to the low privileges of the original HKEY?).
  - This doesn't work *at all* for other users; the app doesn't have permission to use functions like [`RegOpenUserClassesRoot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724899(v=vs.85).aspx) (can't get another user's token) or [`RegOpenCurrentUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894(v=vs.85).aspx) (app is unable to impersonate other users).
- Having the app call `RegOpenUserClassesRoot` and `RegOpenCurrentUser` on the server and pass those HKEYs back to the app (via `DuplicateHandle`, the way it does with all HKEYs). The app then stores those returned keys, and duplicates them to the server when it wants to open a subkey of those keys. This doesn't work either (results in access denied errors).

Things I could try:

- Have the server get the reg keys it needs, on demand, when the client tells it to get a user's HKCU or HKCR. Downside is more overhead on repeated calls (unable to re-use keys, unless a lot of caching goes on), upside is it avoids a `DuplicateHandle` round-drip (which *might* be the problem, somehow...). Seems unlikely to actually solve the problem, but I haven't tried yet.
- Change registry key ACLs to give the app the access it needs directly. This still requires that the server be able to open the registry keys that the user is trying to identify. I'm not even sure that the per-user HKCR union view exists until somebody tries to open that key.
- Go over the code yet again looking for a bug that has thus far eluded me, narrowing down the range of possible causes of the problem. So far this hasn't worked for this problem, though it did let me solve a different one that I had with this RPC server (this is the first large-scale piece of MSRPC code I've written) so maybe I'll get lucky this time. This is also obviously the thing to do if one of the things I've tried *ought* to have worked, but didn't.

Anybody with any experience in this area have an idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You've got the division of responsibilities wrong.  Put all the code that needs to access the registry in the server, the only code that needs to be in the app is the UI.  (That also helps mitigate the security hole you're introducing.)  FWIW, however, you should be able to handle HKCU by opening it directly as a subkey of HKU whose name is the user's SID.  HKCR is probably a lost cause, as I imagine that's some kind of pseudohandle, and so can't be duplicated cross-process.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I was attempting to minimize the performance impact of making lots of calls and shuttling lots of data over RPC, thus the goal of passing HKEYs back and forth rather than data buffers. LRPC is pretty fast, though, and the performance isn't *that* sensitive. Valid point on opening HKU\<SID>, though. As for passing it across... it occurs to me that MSDN doesn't actually say `DuplicateHandle` supports HKEYs from `RegOpenUserClassesRoot` or `RegOpenCurrentUser`. Maybe that's just the problem...

Comment: What do you mean by "a sandboxed app"? A Metro App? App running with a restricted token? What?

Comment: @Ben: Is that relevant? While technically there is a difference between AppContainers and manually-created low-IL restricted tokens, I wouldn't expect them to impact this particular use case. Then again, I'm already running into unexpected behaviors. The sandbox is an AppContainer ("Metro App"). It took some work to get it to connect to RPC at all, but it works fine now except for the problems highlighted above.

Comment: I think you'll find that LRPC is fast enough that the GUI will still be the bottleneck.  Even if it isn't quite as fast that way, I don't think the performance impact will be worth the trouble you're likely to have using an unsupported technique.  (Heck, for all we know, the next release of Windows 10 will explicitly prevent handles from being duplicated into sandboxed applications.)  But yes, my guess is that either HKCR can't be duplicated at all, or can't be duplicated between different sessions.  The sandbox seems the less likely cause.